# Use Google Sheets to create column C by deleting any phrases that contain word found in column B in column A

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

[image]

I have a list in column A and I want to remove any cells that contain any word.

Answer (score 1):

In C2 enter this formula :

```
=filter(
     ArrayFormula(if(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,TEXTJOIN("|",true,B2:B)),,A2:A)),
      ArrayFormula(if(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,TEXTJOIN("|",true,B2:B)),,A2:A))<>""
)
```

---

Breakdown of the formula :

```
   =REGEXMATCH(A2,TEXTJOIN("|",true,B2:B))
```

`Regexmatch` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` if `A2` contains any of the words in column `B`. `TEXJOIN` is self-explanatory, it helps creating a small regex like this one : `value1|value2|value3`.

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,TEXTJOIN("|",true,B2:B)))
```

`Arrayformula` is a way to test the range `A2:A`.

```
ArrayFormula(if(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,TEXTJOIN("|",true,B2:B)),,A2:A))
```

Simple `IF` : if `true` do nothing, if `false`, copy the value.

Last function is a `FILTER` to eliminate every blank entries.
`<>""` is a check for empty values.

Comment: Don't forget to accept whatever answer suits you the most.

Answer (score 1):

```
=FILTER(A2:A, NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B))))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B)), A2:A), NOT(COUNTIF(B2:B, 
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B)), A2:A)))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: @MichaelRock https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers